# CUDA C++ code throwing an error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cuda

My objective is to transform a set of codes written in MATLAB to CUDA C++ for parallel processing on GPU.
This is the MATLAB code I've been trying to transform:

```
function [M] = iqm_czekanowski(img1, img2)
img1 = double(img1);
img2 = double(img2);
[R,C,K] = size(img1);
N2 = R*C;
SUM1 = zeros(R,C);
SUM2 = zeros(R,C);
MIN = min(img1,img2);
%display(size(MIN));
SUM = img1 + img2;
for k=1:K
    SUM1 = SUM1 + MIN(:,:,k);
    SUM2 = SUM2 + SUM(:,:,k);    
end
SUM = (2 .* SUM1) ./ SUM2;
SUM(isnan(SUM))=0;
SUM = 1 - (SUM);
M = sum(sum(SUM)) / N2;
```

The img1 and img2 are 2 rgb images passed as parameters from another script. For simplification, I split the rgb image into 3 different channels img_r, img_b and img_g that represents the r, b and g planes respectively.
This is the piece of CUDA C++ code that throws the error:

```
__global__ void iqm(int *img_r, int *img_g, int *img_b, int *f_img_r, int *f_img_g, int *f_img_b, int *x, int *y, int *z, double *iqm_res){
int n = x[0] * y[0];

//mae and mse
double mae = 0, m1 = 0, m2 = 0, m3 = 0;
double mse = 0, mse1 = 0, mse2 = 0, mse3 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    m1 = m1 + abs(img_r[i] - f_img_r[i]);
    mse1 = mse1 + pow((double)abs(img_r[i] - f_img_r[i]),2.0);
}
m1 = m1 / n;
mse1 = sqrt(mse1 / n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    m2 = m2 + abs(img_g[i] - f_img_g[i]);
    mse2 = mse2 + pow((double)abs(img_g[i] - f_img_g[i]),2.0);
}
m2 = m2 / n;
mse2 = sqrt(mse2 / n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    m3 = m3 + abs(img_b[i] - f_img_b[i]);
    mse3 = mse3 + pow((double)abs(img_b[i] - f_img_b[i]),2.0);
}
m3 = m3 / n;
mse3 = sqrt(mse3 / n);
mae = (m1 + m2 + m3) / z[0];
mse = (mse1 + mse2 + mse3) / z[0];

//iqm_res[0] = mae;
//iqm_res[1] = mse;

//czekanowski
int min_r[26730], min_g[26730], min_b[26730];
int sum_r[26730], sum_g[26730], sum_b[26730];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    if (img_r[i] <= f_img_r[i]){
        min_r[i] = img_r[i];
    }
    else{
        min_r[i] = f_img_r[i];
    }
    sum_r[i] = img_r[i] + f_img_r[i];

    if (img_g[i] <= f_img_g[i]){
        min_g[i] = img_g[i];
    }
    else{
        min_g[i] = f_img_g[i];
    }
    sum_g[i] = img_g[i] + f_img_g[i];

    if (img_b[i] <= f_img_b[i]){
        min_b[i] = img_b[i];
    }
    else{
        min_b[i] = f_img_b[i];
    }
    sum_b[i] = img_b[i] + f_img_b[i];
}

int sum1[26730], sum2[26730];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    sum1[i] = min_r[i] + min_g[i] + min_b[i];
    sum2[i] = sum_r[i] + sum_g[i] + sum_b[i];
}
double sum[26730];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    if (sum2[i] == 0){
        sum[i] = 1.0;
    }
    else{
        sum[i] = 1 - (2 * sum1[i] / sum2[i]);

    }
}
double czekanowski = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    czekanowski += sum[i];
}
czekanowski /= (double)n;
//printf("%f",czekanowski);
iqm_res[0] = mae;
iqm_res[1] = mse;
iqm_res[2] = czekanowski;
}
```

the first three parameters represent the r,g,b channels of first image and the next 3 parameters represent the same for the 2nd image. The very last line of the code

```
    iqm_res[2] = czekanowski;
```

is the one that results in the error.
This is the result I get once I comment the last line

iqm =

```
1.0595    1.9781    0.0065    0.9972    0.9995    0.2892    3.9219    1.3211
```

iqm_res =

```
1.0595    1.9781         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

and the error I get once i uncomment it:

Error using parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel/feval
An unexpected error occurred trying to launch a kernel. The CUDA error was:
CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE

Error in iqm_main_demo (line 59)
[t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,iqm_res] = feval(k,img1_r,img1_g,img1_b,img2_r,img2_g,img2_b,x,y,z,iqm_res);

The mse and mae part work fine and are giving correct results.
Also I would like to ask, if there are any limitations in the size of the images that can be used for the above. I took a large image 1500x1200 and it resulted in a hardware error.

Edit: The whole code including the kernel call.

```
%iqm_main_demo

clear all;

img_sample=imread('onion.png');
gfilt = fspecial('gaussian');
filt_img = imfilter(img_sample, gfilt, 'replicate');
cnt=0;

iqm(cnt+1) = iqm_mae(img_sample, filt_img);
iqm(cnt+2) = iqm_mse(img_sample, filt_img);
iqm(cnt+3) = iqm_czekanowski(img_sample, filt_img);
iqm(cnt+4) = iqm_crosscorr(img_sample, filt_img);
iqm(cnt+5) = iqm_normcrosscorr(img_sample, filt_img);
iqm(cnt+6) = iqm_mas(img_sample, filt_img);
iqm(cnt+7) = iqm_spectralmagnitude(img_sample, filt_img);
iqm(cnt+8) = iqm_spectralphase(img_sample, filt_img);
%iqm(cnt+9) = iqm_hvs(img_sample, filt_img);
%iqm(cnt+10) = iqm_laplacianmse(img_sample, filt_img);
%cnt = cnt + 10;

iqm

k = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('demo.ptx','demo.cu');
k.ThreadBlockSize = [1 1 1];

img1_r = img_sample(:,:,1);
img1_g = img_sample(:,:,2);
img1_b = img_sample(:,:,3);

img2_r = filt_img(:,:,1);
img2_g = filt_img(:,:,2);
img2_b = filt_img(:,:,3);

[x,y,z]=size(img_sample);

img1_r = reshape(img1_r',[1 x*y]);
img1_g = reshape(img1_g',[1 x*y]);
img1_b = reshape(img1_b',[1 x*y]);

img2_r = reshape(img2_r',[1 x*y]);
img2_g = reshape(img2_g',[1 x*y]);
img2_b = reshape(img2_b',[1 x*y]);

img1_r = gpuArray(int32(img1_r));
img1_g = gpuArray(int32(img1_g));
img1_b = gpuArray(int32(img1_b));

img2_r = gpuArray(int32(img2_r));
img2_g = gpuArray(int32(img2_g));
img2_b = gpuArray(int32(img2_b));

x = gpuArray(int32(x));
y = gpuArray(int32(y));
z = gpuArray(int32(z));

iqm_res = gpuArray(zeros(1,10)); 

[t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,iqm_res] = 
feval(k,img1_r,img1_g,img1_b,img2_r,img2_g,img2_b,x,y,z,iqm_res);

iqm_res
```

Comment: Without an [MCVE] it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: IS that piece of cuda code the whole kernel? If that is the case, it is wrong in many levels. Please also put the mex code and kernel calls

Comment: Yes it is the whole kernel. I'm new to CUDA, and I don't have much experience with it. Please mention what is wrong.

Comment: And I can really use tips on how to improve my program. I did this by only watching web tutorials.

Comment: I have no idea on how to write a mex code. I wrote the above code by following this example https://in.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html that uses a cu and ptx file

Comment: Using CUDAKernel, MATLAB lets you launch kernels compiled to PTX directly from MATLAB, so you don't need a mexFunction interface or any host code.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified block dimensions of 1x1x1 for some reason, and you say your input is 1500x1200, requiring 1.8 million blocks. I'm not sure that's possible, so maybe that's the reason. Try commenting out the line

```
k.ThreadBlockSize = [1 1 1];
```

and see if it starts working.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Turns out a thread on a gpu has limited local memory to store its copy of variables (about 64K probably). Declaring all the auxillary arrays was causing the problem. Computing everything directly without any auxillary values solved it.

Comment: Also, I've been using CUDA the wrong way. I assumed that I could have each thread process one image entirely, thus saving time processing the images serially, by processing multiple images at once. To test out my code on a single image, I took ThreadBlockSize = [1 1 1]. After I solved the auxillary array problem, the code still didn't work because of Windows imposing a Kernel Execution Timeout of 2s. Changing the timeout value in the registry fixed the problem. But, now have implemented this problem in a different way which does not cause any memory overflow or timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. Turns out a thread on a gpu has limited local memory to store its copy of variables (about 64K probably). Declaring all the auxillary arrays was causing the problem. Computing everything directly without any auxillary values solved it.

Also, I've been using CUDA the wrong way. I assumed that I could have each thread process one image entirely, thus saving time processing the images serially, by processing multiple images at once. To test out my code on a single image, I took ThreadBlockSize = [1 1 1]. After I solved the auxillary array problem, the code still didn't work because of Windows imposing a Kernel Execution Timeout of 2s. Changing the timeout value in the registry fixed the problem. But, now have implemented this problem in a different way which does not cause any memory overflow or timeouts.